# SQL Server: how to open default trace file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to open the default trace file (log_17.trc) from dir

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.INSTC\MSSQL\Log
```

I get the following error in the SQL Server profiler:

```
Failed to open file. Access is denied
```

I'm using sysadmin account. I'm on Windows 7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recreated the problem on my own Windows 7 machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 SSMS and SQL Server 2008 Data Engine, and I had to start start SQL Profiler in elevated mode (Run as Administrator) to open the default trace files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

SELECT * 
FROM fn_trace_gettable(
  convert (varchar(1000),(SELECT value
   FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
   where traceid = (select max(traceid) from ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)) and property = 2
   ))
, default)